# How to add slimmenu jQuery on external .js file?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is original code and working fine.

```
<script src="src/js/jquery.slimmenu.js"></script>

<script>
$('.slimmenu').slimmenu({
  resizeWidth: '800',
  collapserTitle: 'Main Menu',
  animSpeed:'medium',
  indentChildren: true,
  childrenIndenter: '&raquo;'
});
</script>
```

I just move this code to external js file and menu is not working.

```
$('.slimmenu').slimmenu({
  resizeWidth: '800',
  collapserTitle: 'Main Menu',
  animSpeed:'medium',
  indentChildren: true,
  childrenIndenter: '&raquo;'
});
```

I am new to jQuery. pls help me to move this code to external js file.

Thanks

Comment: source url http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/

Comment: In your HTML, you might be loading external js file before `jquery.slimmenu.js`

Comment: no here is full code.

Comment: Please share your full code.